# MySQL thows error ERROR 2068 (HY000): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access

Tags: mysql

When trying to insert values into a table from a file, MySQL throws this error:

```
ERROR 2068 (HY000): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.
```

The command I am running is:

```
 load data local infile "D://data.txt" into table studentInfo;
```

I have turned the local_infile variable ON as well as Grant file command to root user @ localhost. I am using 8.0 version of MySQL.

What can I do

Comment: See for: `FILE` permissions, `local_infile` and `secure_file_priv` settings, OS account permissions. *I have turned the local_infile variable ON* On both server and client side?